# How can I save overwrites in channel to sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I am now creating server back-up bot, but i got problem in this code. (about overwrites)

```
for overwrite in ctx.guild.channels:
    overwrites = overwrite.overwrites
    allow = discord.Permissions.value
    deny = discord.Permissions.value
    insert_overwrite_info = "INSERT INTO overwrites (id, allowperms, denyperms, targetid, targettype) values (\'%s\', %s, %s, \'%s\', %s)" % (overwrite.id, overwrites.value.from_pair(allow), overwrites.value.from_pair(deny), overwrites.target.id, overwrites.target.type)
    c.execute(insert_overwrite_info)
    conn.commit()
```

and error message is

```
insert_overwrite_info = "INSERT INTO overwrites (id, allowperms, denyperms, targetid, targettype) values (\'%s\', %s, %s, \'%s\', %s)" % (overwrite.id, overwrites.value.from_pair(allow), overwrites.value.from_pair(deny), overwrites.target.id, overwrites.target.type)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: You can see the message.  You are expecting `overwrites` to be an object, but it is a dictionary.  Perhaps you should print "overwrites", "allow", and "deny" to know what you're working with.  BTW, `allow` and `deny` are identical.  That can't be right.

Comment: oh i didn't think of that.
i will try it

Comment: Unrelated: It's a good idea to get in the habit of using [parameter substitution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) (see the section starting "Usually your SQL operations") instead of building the string at runtime to prevent SQL Injection issues.